# Find Lagged Average of Group

Tags: stata

I am trying to create instruments from a three-dimensional panel dataset, as included below:

```
input firm  year    market  price   comp_avg
1   2000    10  1   .
3   2000    10  2   .
3   2001    10  3   .
1   2002    10  4   .
3   2002    10  5   .
1   2000    20  6   .
3   2000    20  7   .
1   2001    20  8   .
2   2001    20  9   .
3   2001    20  10  .
1   2002    20  20  .
2   2002    20  30  .
3   2002    20  40  .
2   2000    30  50  .
1   2001    30  60  .
2   2001    30  70  .
1   2002    30  80  .
2   2002    30  90  .
end
```

The instrument I am trying to create is the lagged (year-1) average price of a firm's competitors (those in the same market) in each market the firm operates in in a given year.

At the moment, I have some code that does the job, but I am hoping that I am missing something and can do this in a more clear or efficient way.

Here is the code:

```
// for each firm
qui levelsof firm, local(firms)
qui foreach f in `firms' {

    // find all years for that firm
    levelsof year if firm == `f', local(years)
    foreach y in `years' {

        // skip first year (because there is no lagged data)
        if `y' == 2000 {
            continue
        }

        // find all markets in that year
        levelsof market if firm == `f' & year == `y', local(mkts)
        local L1 = `y'-1
        foreach m in `mkts' {

            // get average of all compeitors in that market in the year prior
            gen temp = firm != `f' & year == `L1' & market == `m'
            su price if temp
            replace comp_avg = r(mean) if firm == `f' & market == `m' & year == `y'
            drop temp

        }
    }
}
```

The data I am working with are reasonably large (~1 million obs) so the faster the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clear 
input firm  year    market  price   
1   2000    10  1   
3   2000    10  2   
3   2001    10  3   
1   2002    10  4   
3   2002    10  5   
1   2000    20  6   
3   2000    20  7   
1   2001    20  8   
2   2001    20  9   
3   2001    20  10  
1   2002    20  20  
2   2002    20  30  
3   2002    20  40  
2   2000    30  50  
1   2001    30  60  
2   2001    30  70  
1   2002    30  80  
2   2002    30  90  
end

bysort firm market (year) : gen Lprice = price[_n-1] if year - year[_n-1] == 1 

bysort market year : egen total = total(Lprice) 
bysort market year : egen count = count(Lprice) 

gen mean_others = (total - cond(missing(Lprice), 0, Lprice)) /// 
/ (count - cond(missing(Lprice), 0, 1)) 

sort market year 

list market year firm price Lprice mean_others total count, sepby(market year) 

     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | market   year   firm   price   Lprice   price   mean_o~s   total   count |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |     10   2000      1       1        .       1          .       0       0 |
  2. |     10   2000      3       2        .       2          .       0       0 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  3. |     10   2001      3       3        2       3          .       2       1 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  4. |     10   2002      1       4        .       4          3       3       1 |
  5. |     10   2002      3       5        3       5          .       3       1 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  6. |     20   2000      3       7        .       7          .       0       0 |
  7. |     20   2000      1       6        .       6          .       0       0 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  8. |     20   2001      2       9        .       9        6.5      13       2 |
  9. |     20   2001      3      10        7      10          6      13       2 |
 10. |     20   2001      1       8        6       8          7      13       2 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 11. |     20   2002      1      20        8      20        9.5      27       3 |
 12. |     20   2002      3      40       10      40        8.5      27       3 |
 13. |     20   2002      2      30        9      30          9      27       3 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 14. |     30   2000      2      50        .      50          .       0       0 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 15. |     30   2001      2      70       50      70          .      50       1 |
 16. |     30   2001      1      60        .      60         50      50       1 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 17. |     30   2002      2      90       70      90         60     130       2 |
 18. |     30   2002      1      80       60      80         70     130       2 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My approach breaks it down:

1. Calculate the previous price for the same firm and market. (#1 could also be done by declaring a (firm, market) pair a panel.)
2. The mean of other values (here previous prices) in the same market and year is the (sum of others MINUS this price) divided by (number of others MINUS 1).
3. #2 needs a modification as if this price is missing, you need to subtract 0 from both numerator and denominator. Stata's normal rules would render sum MINUS missing as missing, but this firm's previous price might be unknown, yet others in the same market might have known prices.

Note: There are small ways of speeding up your code, but this should be faster (so long as it is correct).

EDIT: Another solution (2 lines) using `rangestat` (must be installed using `ssc inst rangestat`):

```
bysort firm market (year) : gen Lprice = price[_n-1] if year - year[_n-1] == 1 
rangestat Lprice, interval(year 0 0) by(market) excludeself
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's a big speed up and much more clear. Not sure why I couldn't wrap my head around creating the lagged price variable

Comment: @EricHB Another solution offered. One-line solutions welcome.

Comment: It seems your first solution is still a bit faster on my machine, but the rangestat command has very clear syntax, which is always a plus